# Trigger that runs on a scheduled time - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables.

Assignment:

```
ID (INT), 
deadline (DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

StudentAssignmentSolution:

```
ID (INT), solutionDate (DATE TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
state DEFAULT 'NOT SOLVED'
```

'Assignment' table have a trigger, that, automatically inserts into StudentAssignmentSolution, a new row.

What I want to do is: if the current time, is greater than 'Deadline' TIME column from Assignment table, to automatically insert into StudentAssignmentSolution table, at column 'state' the value:'Deadline Missed'. I don't want to manually insert, I want to be automatically, like schedueld.
Thank you =)

Comment: That's not what triggers do. Have a look at [the event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). Besides that, instead of materializing these values, you could easily create them ad hoc when querying. One advantage is that the status automatically adapts should the deadline change for any reason.

Comment: (Same goes for the `'NOT SOLVED'` status BTW, that can be determined if there exists no solution but the deadline isn't due yet. The whole `state` column seems to disposable and prone for inconsistencies.)